# How to handle loading of multiple elements in BackboneJS via a single index.html?

Tags: html, backbone.js, backbone-events

I have an issue in ***loading elements with element ID***.

My requirement is loading pages with multiple languages. I have done javascript functions for that. And it works via button click event(onclick). But it won't work while I render the form-2 from form-1(via BackboneJS). **I found, the issue is that loading elements with element ID**. Because on the first loading of form-1, the form-2 elements are not loading(showing the form-2 elements length as zero).

While in form-2, it works successfully via button click event(onclick). *I just want to render the form-2 from form-1 with the selected language from the radio button as common element in index.html*.

Please follow the code snippets.

In View

```
render: function(){
        this.$el.html(_.template($('#formVisitor').html(), this.visitor.toJSON()));
        $(document).ready(function() {
            if(document.getElementById("linkNL").checked){
                langCheck('NL');
            }else if(document.getElementById("linkFR").checked){
                langCheck('FR');
            }else if(document.getElementById("linkEN").checked){
                langCheck('EN');
            }
        });
        return this;
    }
```

In HTML

```
<ul class="navbarLang">
       <li><input type="radio" name="Lang" value="NL" id="linkNL" onclick="langCheck('NL');">NL</li>
       <li><input type="radio" name="Lang" value="FR" id="linkFR" onclick="langCheck('FR');">FR</li>
       <li><input type="radio" name="Lang" value="EN" id="linkEN" checked="checked" onclick="langCheck('EN');">EN</li>
</ul>
```

Javascript

```
// initialized the params
var linkHead = "";
var link1 = "";        
var link2 = "";        
var link3 = "";
var msg = "";
var profile = "";
...........................
..............................


function loadFR(){
  <!-- page1 -->
    linkHead = "Obtenez l'accès rapide ";
    link1 ="Visiteurs";
    link2 ="Pharmaciens";
    link3 ="Exposants";   

  <!-- page2 -->
    headMsg = "Farma inscription";
    msg = "Veuillez sélecter votre langue et ensuite votre profil pour vous pré enregistrer pour le salon FARMA 2014. Si vous êtes pharmacien, votre N° APB est requis à l’inscription.";
     profile = "Profil "+"<span style='color: red;'>*</span>"+" : ";

     profile_0 = "Choisissez votre profil";
     profile_2 = "Industrie pharmaceutique";
     profile_3 = "Hôpital";
     profile_4 = "Société/Institution";
     profile_5 = "Université";
     profile_6 = "Association";
     profile_7 = "Biologie Clinique";
     profile_8 = "étudiant";
     profile_10 = "wetr";   

     proceed = "Procéder";   
     cancel = "Annuler";
}
function langCheck(lang){
    if(lang == "EN"){
         this.loadEN();
    }
    if(lang == "NL"){
         this.loadNL();
    }
    if(lang == "FR"){
         this.loadFR();
    }
// Elements in form1           
    document.getElementById('quickAccessDisp').innerHTML = linkHead;
    document.getElementById('access1Disp').innerHTML = link1;
    document.getElementById('access2Disp').innerHTML = link2;
    document.getElementById('access3Disp').innerHTML = link3;

// Elements in form2        
   document.getElementById('profileDisp').innerHTML = profile;
   document.getElementById('profile_0Disp').innerHTML = profile_0;
   document.getElementById('profile_2Disp').innerHTML = profile_2;
   document.getElementById('profile_3Disp').innerHTML = profile_3;
   document.getElementById('profile_4Disp').innerHTML = profile_4;
   document.getElementById('profile_5Disp').innerHTML = profile_5;
   document.getElementById('profile_6Disp').innerHTML = profile_6;                    
   document.getElementById('profile_7Disp').innerHTML = profile_7;                     
   document.getElementById('profile_8Disp').innerHTML = profile_8;                      
   document.getElementById('profile_10Disp').innerHTML = profile_10;                       
   document.getElementById('proceedDisp').innerHTML = proceed;
   document.getElementById('cancelDisp').innerHTML = cancel;

// common elements
   document.getElementById('placeMessageHead').innerHTML = headMsg;
   document.getElementById('placeMessage').innerHTML = msg;

}
```

Make Sense..!!

Please help me to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: No it doesn't make too much sense. Take a look to beginner tutorials, here's a great resource: http://backbonetutorials.com/. All I can say from the above code snippet is that, whenever you're accessing DOM elements during `render`, you should do it through `view.$el`. So even if the element isn't yet present in the DOM, Backbone will find it in the view cache. http://backbonejs.org/#View-$el

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more. @akoskm

Comment: In addition to akoskm comment, you almost certainly don't want to be binding a `ready` event handler inside a view's `render` function.

Comment: Okay. Thanks. But can you please explain a bit more about, akoskm said.

@AndrewHubbs

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without some error messages and more of the code but I'd guess you've got a scope issue. In langCheck you use "this" to call loadFR.

Comment: But I have tried without "this", its not working. The important thing to be noted is that it works and loads elements on the manual click event. I think the form-2 elements are not loading(showing the form-2 elements length as zero while I am alerting).
Have you any idea about this?

Comment: I agree with the comments on your question, you should really take a look at some examples. Without more of your code I can't really say what is going on.

Comment: For what it's worth, here's what I'd do.
First, I'd suggest avoiding putting things in the global namespace, wrap those radiobuttons into a view, create a Model with languages and pass the model to the radio button view and the form views and have them listen to changes on the model. Take a look at the Backbone documentation and tutorials for similar examples.